What is the difference between Google's AI agent builders?
The company I work for decided they need AI agent bots. As with all software engineering things there seems to be multiple ways of doing this using google's tooling. I noticed there is a Vertex AI ANN Service and there is also the AgentBuilder which is a service provided in GCP. The AI ANN method involves vectorizing the data and just seems a bit more complicated. The AgentBuilder is very much plug and play. That is, just upload your data and ask your agent questions about it and it just works.... The agentbuilder seems way easier, why would somebody choose one or the other for implementing a chatbot?
thanks in advance
